# Making a dropdown menu using HTML and CSS on a navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have most of the HTML and CSS written for the dropdown menu, however I can't get the dropdown menu to be stacked vertically, it is displayed horizontally. How can I make it so it is stacked vertically? [This is a picture of what the horizontal menu looks like, the second element I want is off the screen because it is next to the first one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKUlD.png)

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!-- Buttons to navigate site -->
        <div class = "navbar">
            <button id = "home"><a href = "index.html">Home</a></button>
            <button id = "aboutus"><a href = "aboutus.html">About Us</a></button>
            <!-- Wellness Dropdown Menu -->
            <div class = "dropdown">
                <button id = "wellness"><a href = "wellness.html">Wellness</a></button>
                <div class = "dropdown-content">
                    <a href = "recipe.html">Recipes</a>
                    <a href = "blog.html">Blog</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
/*-----------
Dropdown Menu
-------------*/
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 180px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    color: #efdcaf;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover #wellness {
  color: #efdcaf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because a tags are displayed inline.
Use display block to fix your problem.

```
.dropdown-content a {
display: block;
padding: 5px 20px;
cursor: pointer;
border: none;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:block;` and move the text towards `left`;

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-width: 180px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: #efdcaf;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover #wellness {
  color: #efdcaf;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <button id="home"><a href = "index.html">Home</a></button>
  <button id="aboutus"><a href = "aboutus.html">About Us</a></button>
  <!-- Wellness Dropdown Menu -->
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button id="wellness"><a href = "wellness.html">Wellness</a></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="recipe.html">Recipes</a>
      <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update **.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content** as below.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```css
button {
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 180px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    color: #efdcaf;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.dropdown:hover #wellness {
    color: #efdcaf;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <button id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></button>
    <button id="aboutus"><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></button>
    <!-- Wellness Dropdown Menu -->
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button id="wellness"><a href="wellness.html">Wellness</a></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="recipe.html">Recipes</a>
            <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```